# Texture for Superpixels?

Tags: computer-vision, textures, feature-extraction

Since superpixels have irregular shape, I am not sure how to extract the texture features for them. All the techniques that I have found online require a rectangular image for extracting texture information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two methods I can think of.
Either compute the filter response on the entire undivided image and group the responses in each superpixel, or compute color histogram of the superpixel as an approximation for a texture feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way. Find center of each superpixel. Taking this center, form a patch of some size like 20x20 around this center. Extract features from this 20x20 patch and pass it into a classifier. I am using this way in my research and it is working perfectly for me.