# How to extract features from supervoxels?

Tags: 3d, feature-extraction

I heard features concerning color (histogram), texture (local binary pattern), and shape (SIFT, BoW, HOG, HOF), but I do not know how to calculate them.

Answer (score 0):

First,  I don't think you mean supervoxels, but I could be wrong. Superpixels appears to be the term you are looking for which would explain the relative lack of response, supervoxels refer to 3D space, however the techniques described below should be equivalent in N dimensional space.

see [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=superpixels)   many questions (though still, not many talk about feature extraction, and I don't feel this question is a duplicate)

To try to give you some semblance of answer, according to
[Texture for Superpixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512807/texture-for-superpixels), you can find the answers to these question via finding centriod of each superpixel and finding the area round that to calculate (ie 20 x 20 pixels).  I would suggest if you were going to do this, and you have width and height information of super pixel, scale this 20x20 area based upon those dimensions. Conventional methods for feature extraction should work then regardless, and could be highly paralleled depending on implementation.

If you don't want to go down this route, the following could work

To start with [color histogram](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html), this should work the same way as any other square image segmentation algorithm, you simply look at all the pixels and accumulate color values into a histogram, I don't see why this would be difficult.

for texture information, depending on which types of features you wish to extract, it can be more or less complicated, if your features are spatially invariant this becomes as easy as color histogram.  For [local binary pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) you simply find the centriod of the super pixel and assume the same algorithm (click the link to figure out how it works if you've never implemented it yourself). You would presumably ignore areas outside the superpixel.

If I understand [HOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) it is also invariant to the shape of what you are working with, which means you can compute it per superpixel assuming you have subpixel information.  HOF (I had to look this up there is no information on this through a wiki) Histogram of optical flow theoretically would have the same properties (histogram based method) so computing it given super pixels should be possible via the same logic. ([HOF and HOG lecture discussing algorithm](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Gerard.Lacey/Gerard_Lacey_Homepage/CS4053_Course_files/Lecture%20009%20HOG-HOF.pdf))

[BOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) to my knowledge is not a specific feature extraction technique and is a general model, so I'm going to ignore this one.

[SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) features can be extracted via normal methods of computation, the fact that superpixels are not regular rectangles does not appear to matter in the computation of SIFT features (algorithm outline provided in SIFT link)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I mean supervoxels rather than superpixels. I had added a "3d" tag for this question. However, they are somewhat similar, and your information is helpful.